# CUPS - jobs getting cancelled on Canon imageRUNNER ADVANCE C5535 via IPP

Tags: cups

I'm trying to setup Canon imageRUNNER ADVANCE C5535 to print with CUPS via IPP.

1. I've enabled IPP in the printer admin
2. I've added the printer to CUPS with the manufacturer's driver (Canon iR-ADV C5535/5540 UFR II) and url "http://10.11.75.21/ipp" (10.11.75.21 is the printer's IP)
3. I'm printing the test page via the CUPS' web interface.
4. The job is marked as completed, but no page is printed.

After digging into logs, it seems that the printer is cancelling the jobs. I have no idea why. The logs are here:

```
[Job 818] Adding start banner page "none".
[Job 818] Adding end banner page "none".
[Job 818] File of type application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner queued by "adam".
[Job 818] hold_until=0
[Job 818] Queued on "TestPrinter" by "adam".
[Job 818] time-at-processing=1552920893
[Job 818] 4 filters for job:
[Job 818] bannertopdf (application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner to application/pdf, cost 32)
[Job 818] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
[Job 818] pdftops (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-postscript, cost 100)
[Job 818] pstoufr2cpca (application/vnd.cups-postscript to printer/TestPrinter, cost 0)
[Job 818] job-sheets=none,none
[Job 818] argv[0]="TestPrinter"
[Job 818] argv[1]="818"
[Job 818] argv[2]="adam"
[Job 818] argv[3]="Test Page"
[Job 818] argv[4]="1"
[Job 818] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:9469ef0d-c597-3645-4c77-59d691976a22 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= 
[Job 818] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00818-001"
[Job 818] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
[Job 818] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
[Job 818] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
[Job 818] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
[Job 818] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
[Job 818] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
[Job 818] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
[Job 818] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
[Job 818] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
[Job 818] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
[Job 818] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@adam-HP-ENVY-Notebook"
[Job 818] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.1.3"
[Job 818] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
[Job 818] envp[13]="USER=root"
[Job 818] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
[Job 818] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
[Job 818] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
[Job 818] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
[Job 818] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
[Job 818] envp[19]="LANG=cs_CZ.UTF-8"
[Job 818] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/TestPrinter.ppd"
[Job 818] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
[Job 818] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner"
[Job 818] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=http://10.11.75.21/ipp"
[Job 818] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=TestPrinter"
[Job 818] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
[Job 818] envp[26]="PRINTER=TestPrinter"
[Job 818] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=media-empty-report"
[Job 818] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
[Job 818] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-postscript"
[Job 818] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
[Job 818] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf (PID 31242)
[Job 818] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 31243)
[Job 818] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops (PID 31244)
[Job 818] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca (PID 31245)
[Job 818] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/http (PID 31246)
[Job 818] pstoufr2cpca start.
[Job 818] pdftops - copying to temp print file \"/tmp/07a0c5c91d9a7\"
[Job 818] PDF template file doesn\'t have form. It\'s okay.
[Job 818] Sending stdin for job...
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=0(), s=\"+connecting-to-device\")
[Job 818] STATE: +connecting-to-device
[Job 818] Looking up \"10.11.75.21\"...
[Job 818] Printer make and model: Canon ir-adv c5535/5540 iii
[Job 818] Running command line for pstops: pstops 818 adam \'Test Page\' 1 \'job-uuid=urn:uuid:9469ef0d-c597-3645-4c77-59d691976a22 
[Job 818] Using image rendering resolution 600 dpi
[Job 818] Running command line for gs: gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOUTPUTFILE=%stdout -dLanguageLevel=3 -r600 
[Job 818] PID 31243 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
[Job 818] Started filter gs (PID 31247)
[Job 818] PID 31242 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf) exited with no errors.
[Job 818] Started filter pstops (PID 31248)
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-colors=#000000,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,none,#000000,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-names=\'\"Canon C-EXV 51 Black Toner\"\',\'\"Canon C-EXV 51 Cyan Toner\"\',\'\"Canon C-EXV 51 Magenta 
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-types=toner,toner,toner,toner,waste-toner,opc,opc,opc,opc
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-levels=44,67,68,69,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
[Job 818] new_supply_state=0, change_state=ffff
[Job 818] STATE: -developer-low-report
[Job 818] STATE: -developer-empty-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -marker-supply-low-report
[Job 818] STATE: -marker-supply-empty-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -opc-near-eol-report
[Job 818] STATE: -opc-life-over-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -toner-low-report
[Job 818] STATE: -toner-empty-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -waste-receptacle-almost-full-report
[Job 818] STATE: -waste-receptacle-full-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -cleaner-life-almost-over-report
[Job 818] STATE: -cleaner-life-over-warning
[Job 818] new_state=8000, change_state=ffff
[Job 818] STATE: -media-empty-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -door-open-report
[Job 818] STATE: -media-jam-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -input-tray-missing-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -output-tray-missing-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -marker-supply-missing-warning
[Job 818] STATE: -output-area-almost-full-report
[Job 818] STATE: -output-area-full-warning
[Job 818] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=7, addr=0x55b242359568, side_cb=0x55b2411bad10)
[Job 818] Page = 595x842; 14,14 to 581,828
[Job 818] slow_collate=0, slow_duplex=0, slow_order=0
[Job 818] Before copy_comments - %!PS-Adobe-3.0
[Job 818] %!PS-Adobe-3.0
[Job 818] %%BoundingBox: 0 0 595 842
[Job 818] %%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 595.00 842.00
[Job 818] %%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 926 (ps2write)
[Job 818] %%LanguageLevel: 2
[Job 818] %%CreationDate: D:20190318155453+01\'00\'
[Job 818] %%Pages: 1
[Job 818] %%EndComments
[Job 818] Before copy_prolog - %%BeginProlog
[Job 818] Before copy_setup - %%Page: 1 1
[Job 818] Before page loop - %%Page: 1 1
[Job 818] Copying page 1...
[Job 818] pagew = 566.9, pagel = 813.5
[Job 818] bboxx = 0, bboxy = 0, bboxw = 595, bboxl = 842
[Job 818] PageLeft = 14.2, PageRight = 581.1
[Job 818] PageTop = 827.8, PageBottom = 14.3
[Job 818] PageWidth = 595.0, PageLength = 842.0
[Job 818] opvpOpenPrinter(391)
[Job 818] CStubOpenPrinter(330)
[Job 818] opvpOpenPrinter(391)
[Job 818] CStubOpenPrinter(330)
[Job 818] Connecting to 10.11.75.21:80
[Job 818] Connecting to printer.
[Job 818] Set job-printer-state-message to "Connecting to printer.", current level=INFO
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=0(), s=\"-cups-certificate-error\")
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=0(), s=\"-connecting-to-device\")
[Job 818] STATE: -connecting-to-device
[Job 818] Connected to printer.
[Job 818] Set job-printer-state-message to "Connected to printer.", current level=INFO
[Job 818] Connected to 10.11.75.21:80...
[Job 818] Getting supported attributes...
[Job 818] Get-Printer-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] copies-supported=1-9999
[Job 818] document-format-supported (3 values)
[Job 818] [0] = \"application/octet-stream\"
[Job 818] [1] = \"image/jpeg\"
[Job 818] [2] = \"application/pdf\"
[Job 818] media-col-supported (9 values)
[Job 818] [0] = \"media-size\"
[Job 818] [1] = \"media-bottom-margin\"
[Job 818] [2] = \"media-left-margin\"
[Job 818] [3] = \"media-right-margin\"
[Job 818] [4] = \"media-top-margin\"
[Job 818] [5] = \"media-type\"
[Job 818] [6] = \"media-source\"
[Job 818] [7] = \"media-source-properties\"
[Job 818] [8] = \"media-auto-dimension\"
[Job 818] operations-supported (9 values)
[Job 818] [0] = Print-Job
[Job 818] [1] = Validate-Job
[Job 818] [2] = Create-Job
[Job 818] [3] = Send-Document
[Job 818] [4] = Cancel-Job
[Job 818] [5] = Get-Job-Attributes
[Job 818] [6] = Get-Jobs
[Job 818] [7] = Get-Printer-Attributes
[Job 818] [8] = Identify-Printer
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=1(media-empty-report), s=\"(null)\")
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-colors=\'\"#000000\"\',\'\"#00FFFF\"\',\'\"#FF00FF\"\',\'\"#FFFF00\"\'
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-high-levels=100,100,100,100
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-levels=42,67,68,69
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-low-levels=7,7,7,7
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-names=\'\"Canon C-EXV 51 Black Toner\"\',\'\"Canon C-EXV 51 Cyan Toner\"\',\'\"Canon C-EXV 51 Magenta 
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-types=\'\"toner\"\',\'\"toner\"\',\'\"toner\"\',\'\"toner\"\'
[Job 818] final_content_type=\"application/vnd.cups-postscript\", document_format=\"application/octet-stream\"
[Job 818] Validate-Job IPP/2.0
[Job 818] printer-uri=\"http://10.11.75.21:80/ipp\"
[Job 818] requesting-user-name=\"adam\"
[Job 818] job-name=\"Test Page\"
[Job 818] document-format=\"application/octet-stream\"
[Job 818] IPP/2.0 Validate-Job #2
[Job 818] ---- operation-attributes-tag ----
[Job 818] attributes-charset charset utf-8
[Job 818] attributes-natural-language naturalLanguage cs-cz
[Job 818] printer-uri uri http://10.11.75.21:80/ipp
[Job 818] requesting-user-name nameWithoutLanguage adam
[Job 818] job-name nameWithoutLanguage Test Page
[Job 818] document-format mimeMediaType application/octet-stream
[Job 818] ---- end-of-attributes-tag ----
[Job 818] Validate-Job: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=1(media-empty-report), s=\"(null)\")
[Job 818] Get-Printer-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] Create-Job IPP/2.0
[Job 818] printer-uri=\"http://10.11.75.21:80/ipp\"
[Job 818] requesting-user-name=\"adam\"
[Job 818] job-name=\"Test Page\"
[Job 818] IPP/2.0 Create-Job #4
[Job 818] ---- operation-attributes-tag ----
[Job 818] attributes-charset charset utf-8
[Job 818] attributes-natural-language naturalLanguage cs-cz
[Job 818] printer-uri uri http://10.11.75.21:80/ipp
[Job 818] requesting-user-name nameWithoutLanguage adam
[Job 818] job-name nameWithoutLanguage Test Page
[Job 818] ---- end-of-attributes-tag ----
[Job 818] Create-Job: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] Print job accepted - job ID 18.
[Job 818] Sending file 1 using chunking...
[Job 818] PID 31247 (gs) exited with no errors.
[Job 818] Wrote 1 pages...
[Job 818] PID 31248 (pstops) exited with no errors.
[Job 818] PID 31244 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops) exited with no errors.
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=1(media-empty-report), s=\"(null)\")
[Job 818] Get-Printer-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] (monitor) Get-Job-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] (monitor) job-state = pending
[Job 818] (monitor) job-state = pending
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=1(media-empty-report), s=\"(null)\")
[Job 818] Get-Printer-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] (monitor) Get-Job-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] (monitor) job-state = pending
[Job 818] (monitor) job-state = pending
[Job 818] update_reasons(attr=1(media-empty-report), s=\"(null)\")
[Job 818] Get-Printer-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] (monitor) Get-Job-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] (monitor) job-state = canceled
[Job 818] (monitor) job_canceled = -1
[Job 818] (monitor) job-state = canceled
i[Job 818] Get-Printer-Attributes: successful-ok (successful-ok)
[Job 818] ATTR: marker-levels=42,67,68,69,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
[Job 818] new_supply_state=0, change_state=0
[Job 818] new_state=8000, change_state=0
[Job 818] ATTR: auth-info-required=none
[Job 818] Print job canceled at printer.
[Job 818] Set job-printer-state-message to "Print job canceled at printer.", current level=ERROR
[Job 818] PID 31246 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/http) stopped with status 5.
```

I thought that there could be an issue with authentication, so I tried changing the printer's url to http://name:password@10.11.75.21/ipp (is this the right way to autenticate?), but the only result was that the jobs got stuck on processing.